# Angular time input

Tags: angularjs, html, time, hour

Is there any way I can increase the hours range on Angular time input for beyond 23?
This is what I'm trying to do:

```
<input id="deliveryTime" type="time" placeholder="00:00" min="00:00" max="900:59"ng-model="currentEditingEntity.deliveryTime"/>
```

But it seens the "max" attribute do not work this way. I have tried ng-max but still got no results.

Comment: I don't think this is an Angular issue, it's just how the time input field is implemented in html. You could create a custom input type to help achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, I'm newbie in web development, thought it was an Angular issue. I'm gonna look for how to create a custom input field. Thank you.